# Chained arrow function in react/material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I got this code from the Material UI docs on [Accordion](https://material-ui.com/components/accordion/#accordion). I have been studying this code for hours, I can't wrap my head around how it works:

```js
export default function CustomizedAccordions() {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState('panel1');

  const handleChange = (panel) => (event, newExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(newExpanded ? panel : false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Accordion square expanded={expanded === 'panel1'} onChange={handleChange('panel1')}>
        <AccordionSummary aria-controls="panel1d-content" id="panel1d-header">
          <Typography>Collapsible Group Item #1</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex,
            sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
            elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion square expanded={expanded === 'panel2'} onChange={handleChange('panel2')}>
        <AccordionSummary aria-controls="panel2d-content" id="panel2d-header">
          <Typography>Collapsible Group Item #2</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex,
            sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
            elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion square expanded={expanded === 'panel3'} onChange={handleChange('panel3')}>
        <AccordionSummary aria-controls="panel3d-content" id="panel3d-header">
          <Typography>Collapsible Group Item #3</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex,
            sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
            elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Specifically this line:

```js
const handleChange = (panel) => (event, newExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(newExpanded ? panel : false);
  };
```

Where is this newExpanded argument coming from? and how is it a Boolean?

Comment: `Accordion` is passing both of those arguments, `event` and `newExpanded`, by calling its `onChange` prop with them. `handleChange` is a _higher-order_ function, it's a _factory_ that creates and returns a change-handling function.

Comment: What it looks like not written as arrow functions `function handleChange(panel){ return function (event, newExpanded) { setExpanded(newExpanded ? panel : false); }}` So when handleChange is called it returns a function. That function is assigned to the click event handler which passes the event object and the state. The `newExpanded` is passed from the accordion component

Comment: `newExpanded` is passed by the `Accordion` component when you trigger the `onChange` event. [See the `onChange` prop of `Accordion`](https://material-ui.com/api/accordion/#props)

Comment: Without using a curried function (or as you call it, chained arrow function), the component might have looked like [this](https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/ec38913d2e6cf421eb0d03c59d850f6c).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that it was this specific MaterialUI Component which was passing those arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of closure. You definitely should read about closures more, it is important to understand it well, since it is a common patterns in JS world.

```js
const handleChange = (panel) => (event, newExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(newExpanded ? panel : false);
  };

const newFunction = handleChange('nameOfPanel');

newFunction(someEvent, newExpandedValue);
```

Check out my example. Notice that calling `handleChange` returns new function(i named it `newFunction` ;)). When you call the returned function, you pass these two arguments: `event` and `newExpanded`, and then in the body of this function, so this part:

```js
  setExpanded(newExpanded ? panel : false);
```

the value of `panel` is remembered from the time I created the `newFunction`, so `panel === 'nameOfPanel'`

I know that it might seem to be complicated, but try playing with this pattern a little bit and it will get easier :D